# Show all dates from between

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT `total_user`, `created_date` 
FROM `logs` 
WHERE `logs`.`created_date` BETWEEN '2020-01-13' AND '2020-11-13'
```

which is working fine. but in my records few dates doesn't exist. Is there any way to show all dates from '2020-01-13' to '2020-11-13' even  no date exist

Comment: It is possible but MySQL is not good at this. You should do that in your program logic

Answer (score -1):

Use the technique here ([generate days from date range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157282/generate-days-from-date-range)) to create a date range as a sub query the left join with logs table.